# increase the scannig area for barcode reader

Tags: android, zxing

I have successfully integrate zxing scanner to my application.

I want to increase scanning are,and as the device resolution got changes screen set automatically.

I don`t want to give static height width.

I go through many blogs and solution but no one can able to give perfect solution

Any kind of help appreciated.

Thank you
HapPy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are talking about when you say the "scanning area", but I guess this the framingRect in zxing.

When you say that you have integrated the zxing scanner into your app: I guess you have made a library from [this project](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/android) and that you are simply using it.

The framingRect if by default 5/8 screen dimension. It is defined in [CameraManager.java](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraManager.java) so if you really need to change it that's where you have to go.

---

In CameraManager.java you have this :

```
private static int findDesiredDimensionInRange(int resolution, int hardMin, int hardMax) {
    int dim = 5 * resolution / 8; // Target 5/8 of each dimension
```

So to increase the area just change the 5 and the 8 according your needs. Also take a look at MAX_FRAME_WIDTH and MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT : this the maximum.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
yes i have added this (https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android)library to my project.
Where to change in camara manager.
In my samsung s4 scanner is very small i want to make it bit larger.